# MySQL strange situation : Cannot connect while others can?

Tags: mysql

I was remotely connecting MySQL databases at my website provider without any problem until a few days ago. Then, it stopped working with Time Out Error and/or Connection refused.

Ping to the remote server is always ok, tracert / traceroute to port 3306 is ok. My provider is using a simple PC as a proxy to the local network where the databased are hosted.

Despite this, I cannot connect anymore with my unchanged Python script ( pymysql.cursors used ) or with MySQL Workbench. I tried from a different fresh PC and it was then working while the previous one was no more working at all. After a while ( 1 day ), the second PC stopped working without any change done ( PC was only off during the night ).

I also tested connection from home ( different networks, etc ... ) and, despite the fact it was also working before on my first PC from home, this time even from a Raspberry Pi was I not able to have a connection.

Both the website provider and I have made numerous testing and they confirmed they were able to connect from different places in the world ( via VPN ) without any problem ( even with a 5G phone). So I am now having the impression the problem can potentially come from outside the web provider ( network, ... ? ), even perhaps more locally.

Do you have any idea where I can now start searching to debug this strange problem as I am running out of ideas ?

Cordially,

Luc

Comment: Ping on remote server, traceroute / tracert on port 3306 are all OK. Tests were made on port 3316 ( open for testing ) and all were OK. A new database was created with same problem "only" from my site at different sites.

Comment: Is there a limitation on source host ? What does `select user,host from mysql.user;` return? A value of `%` for host means anywhere. What is the host for your intended user ?